# Can Swiftpad boots be used in a vertical jump?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, movement

I just found some Swiftpad boots as treasure in the 4e game I play in.

Power (Daily): Move Action. You jump a number of squares equal to your Strength modifier.

The power doesn't define whether the jump is horizontal only or can also be used in a vertical jump.

Comment: Note the wording -- "**equal** to your strength modifier". Want to jump a shorter distance? Too bad!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it doesn't say, then it works for any jump.  Magic!

Comment: A wizard did it.

Comment: Something else of note: this means you can jump diagonally in the air as well. So if the OP's secret ambition is to leap tall buildings in a single bound, all he really needs is these boots and about a 30 STR.

Comment: Being trained in Acrobatics might help for the landing...

Comment: I would concur with the "works for any jump" answer. As the DM, I would definitely force an Acrobatics check on the landing if the jump was vertical, regardless of whether they were jumping to a higher ledge or if they were just going straight up and straight down. Failed Acrobatics check = standard damage from falling (especially if the jump would take them up higher than the ledge's height). The power's description says nothing about a safe landing, after all.